# How to keep user logged after browser closing in React - Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am developing an application in React - Express - Mongo, how can i keep the user logged even after the browser is closed or page is refreshed?

Comment: You need to store token in cookie or localstorage and on refresh check if your token is valid.

Comment: @FiodorovAndrei i'm not using any token in backend, only email and password, should I?

Comment: You need to implement a authentication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication

Comment: We don't know how you are currently handling  authentication, so it is hard to suggest ways to change it to persist the login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store JWT Token in LocalStorage or Cookies. That's the Simplest way.

check out here - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-persist-a-logged-in-user-in-react/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A simple example for your understanding ,how to usage of localStorage,
sessionStorage.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-local-storage-session-storage-and-cookies/

```
// After hitting login button

const handleSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const user = { username, password };
  // send the username and password to the server
  const response = await axios.post(
    "http://blogservice.herokuapp.com/api/login",
    user
  );
  // set the state of the user
  setUser(response.data)
  // store the user in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('user', response.data)
  console.log(response.data)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

- create a jwt token in the login API call and return it when you log
  in as a response
- store them in Cookies storage or local storage (I suggest using
  cookies)
- check whether the token exists or not on the login page or signup
  page if it exists redirect the page to the login

Answer (score 0):

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
   const localstorageGetInformation=localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn')
    if(localstorageGetInformation=='1'){
      setIsLoggedIn(true)
    }
  },[])

  const loginHandler = (email, password) => {
    
    localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn",'1')
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This has the same issue as `@andriycode`'s answer. Storing a flag like this in localstorage presents some big security risks.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have something like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
   const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
   // your code
}
```

you could do something like this:

```
const initialLoggedInState = localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
const MyComponent = () => {
   const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(initialLoggedInState === 'true');
   
   useEffect(() => {
      localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', isLoggedIn);
   }, [isLoggedIn]);
   // your code
}
```

Comment: This technically does give a solution to the problem, but has a few huge security issues. Users can manually go into localstorage and set the `isLoggedIn` flag to true and simply log in without credentials. Also, it's very good practice to have sessions expire and this doesn't happen with a simple flag set in localstorage. It's best to use JWT or something similar to persist sessions.

Comment: @WilleyOhana That is why I used the word "could". It wasn't a "should" and it wasn't a question about if it was secure or not. Asking simple questions should not always give you the most sophisticated, secure and complete answers. I know it is not secure and I should probably just mention it in my answer. But as you wrote, it is one technical solution to the problem. A valid one. Not a secure one, but a valid one.